# Deploy Grape API with Nginx/Passenger

Tags: ruby, nginx, passenger, rack, grape-api

I have Nginx and Passenger installed on my server. Trying to run a Grape (Rack) API off it.

When I deploy Rails applications I have this server block in Nginx conf;

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourserver.com;

    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    root /path-to-app/public;

    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_ruby /path-to-ruby;
}
```

The instructions on Passenger's [tutorial](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/nginx/deploy/ruby/#deploying-an-app-to-a-virtual-host-s-root) are;

> The server block's root must point to your application's public
>   subdirectory.

What would this root be in case of my Grape API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of grape, you need to create an empty public folder and point to this folder in the sever block.